# Firefox lagging when having multiple windows open on different workspaces

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, lag

I'm noticing that Firefox on Ubuntu started lagging recently whenever I'm opening multiple windows on distinct workspaces (for example 1 window each on 3 workspaces). It never used to do this, but since a few days/weeks it does.

Minimizing these windows solves this problem, but I'd like to keep these windows open for quick traversal of workspaces. Is there some way to tell Firefox to not "focus on" open windows on other workspaces, so as not to lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer after having tested multiple changes in `about:config` I hope I narrowed it down correctly:

Open a new tab and go to `about:config`, search for `gfx.webrender.software` and set it to `true`.

You may need to restart your Firefox/computer for it to take effect.